# Proper inclusion implies ideal is not power of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $P,Q$ be ideals such that $P^{2} \subset Q \subset P$ where $\subset$ means proper inclusion and such that $P$ is a prime ideal. Can you please explain why this implies that the ideal $Q$ is never a power of the ideal $P$?

Comment: Isn't this simply because, for $n>2$, $P^n\subset P^2\subsetneq Q$?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: doh, right, thanks.

Comment: this holds even if $P$ is not prime.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\ $ divides $\: \Rightarrow\: $ contains:$\rm\ \ \ P^2\ |\ P^{n+2}\ \Rightarrow\ P^2\supset P^{n+2}$